# tmux change copy mode key maps

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to remap the controls in the copy mode of tmux?
I want to remap a few keys in the vi layout of the copy mode.

Yes, I've googled the problem. A lot. I haven't found a way to remap the copy mode keybinding, just the ability to switch between vi and emacs layout. I have a non-standard keyboard layout, neither of these is particularly useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

```
bind-key -t vi-copy n cursor-down
bind-key -t vi-copy r cursor-up
bind-key -t vi-copy b cursor-left
bind-key -t vi-copy s cursor-right
```

This will list your current bindings: `tmux list-keys -t vi-copy`

Found here: http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/vi-mode-in-tmux/